# Spring RestTemplate PostforObject: Unsupported Media Type

Tags: spring, http, rest

I'm trying to execute a RESTful web service, however, when I send the request, HttpClientErrorException occurs with "415 Unsupported Media Type" as the message.

This is the code for the service call:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
request.add(val1, "xxxxx");
request.add(val2, "************");
request.add(val3, "xxx");
request.add("type", "AUTHENTICATE");

String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

The restTemplate is wired from an applicationContext.xml, with a FormHttpMessageConverter as its messageConverter.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg name="requestFactory" ref="httpClientFactory"/>
<property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>
<bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
    <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionManagerClass"
                  value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams"/>
</bean>
```

This is the exception that occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:279)
    at ph.com.smart.drawbridge.commons.diameter.DiameterClient.post(DiameterClient.java:21)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

This problem happens when your client sends a request of media type that the server does not know how to handle. For example, your server method that handles `url` can handle requests of type `application/json` but you sent `text/xml`. The server can't process such request. In order to fix this, find out which `content-type` (media type) the server expects, set a header in your `restTemplate` object that sets `content-type:application/json` (replace `application/json` with whatever the server expects). Also, make sure the request is sent in the correct format (if we're talking about `json` you need to have the `jackson` dependencies that can serialize your object into `json` object).

Answer (score 0):

You probably might not need this now but I am sharing this for anyone who comes across this type of problem in future.

As @Avi pointed out, this problem does happen when your server expects a different media type compared to what you are sending in your request.

In my case I was sending Form data with `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` whereas my server expected Mutipart form data. Adding below header to my request solved my problem:

```
HttpHeaders headers = getBasicAuthHttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```